# VBA to create a dynamic rolling list of names

Tags: excel, vba

I have a base list of staff names that are in a set order. For example:

1. Mathew
2. Mark
3. Luke
4. John

I use this list of names as the basis for a "working list" of names that I use to create monthly work rotas, rolling through the  working list to fill each day of the month. In the interest of fairness, when I create the next month I start from where I left off e.g. April 30th was Mark therefore May 1st will be Luke. My working list would then look like this:

1. Luke
2. John
3. Mathew
4. Mark

At the moment I set the name of the person to start the next working list from and then I use formulas in the cells below to create the working list.

This works fine but when the list expands I have to manually adjust the formulas to take in to account the change in numbers of names in the list and this is time consuming with potential for error.

I'm looking for a VBA solution that would create my working list as described above but without formulas and also when my base list expands or contracts it acts dynamically to accommodate this.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

An example if I get you right. Important is that the red cells have no value.
New Names you just add below the last name.
This is only a simple example for an active sheet

[image]

```
Sub RollIt()
Dim ra As Range, i As Long, v() As Variant
Dim temp As String
Set ra = Range("B2").CurrentRegion
v = ra.Value
temp = v(1, 1)
For i = 2 To UBound(v)
v(i - 1, 1) = v(i, 1)
Next i
v(UBound(v), 1) = temp
ra.Value = v

End Sub
```